# How to catch an error using try and catch for multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, try-catch

i have try an catch function just wanted to understand error scenario, my 2nd function is dependent on 1st. so if first function fails catch will return error but if second function fails i want to use same catch to throw error, its not happening with below code can i implement this logic or i have to implement two seprate try and catch ?

main.js

```
try {

    //1st function 
    specialtyRefillsCache = await new CacheUtility().refillsCache(request.uniqueRxIds)
    const rxInfosArray = specialtyRefillsCache.map((rxInfo: any) => {
        return this.mapSpecialtyRequest(rxInfo);
    });
    if (rxInfosArray.length > 0) {
        const tokenID = request.body.tokenID;
        // 2nd function
        const specialtyMembersInfoCache =
            await new CacheUtility().MemberInfoCache(tokenID);
        this.rxInfos = rxInfosArray;
    }

} catch (e) {
    return this.errorHandler(request, 'no patient info for given HBS ID');
}
```

Comment: do you throw an Error when the "second function fails?"

Comment: @quirimmo yes i have error coming from the function but question is how do i throw   back to caller, do i need to add another catch for second function ? i wanted to use same error handler for second function

Answer (score 0):

simple case which I hope represents your problem

```
function f1(num){
    if(num > 6){
        return 10;
    } 
    else{
        throw new Error("Error from 1st function");
    }
}

function f2(){
   throw new Error("I am an error from 2nd function");
}

function junk(){
    try {
      var a=f1(7);
      if(a === 10){
         f2();
      }

     } catch(e){
         console.log(e);
     } 
}
```